# Windows 7 PC picking up wrong domain on network share

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, dns, domain

I have a network share `\\myshare\my_dir` and it had been working for quite some time without any issues. Now, suddenly, I cannot connect to the share.

I sent a ping request for `\\myshare` and it appends a random domain to the address. Ex `10.0.200.10.notmydomain.com`.

Seeing as that is not my domain I tried to connect to `\\myshare.mydomain.com` This works! However if I try to accesss my_dir like `\\myshare.mydomain.com\my_dir` I cannot access it.

What would cause `notmydomain.com` to append to the network share address? How can I get rid of it?

Additional interesting facts: 
I can connect to the share while I'm on the network VPN and it does not append `notmydomain.com` to the address. This only happens when I'm on the physical network. No other users on the network seem to be experiencing this problem.

I have tried `ipconfig /release & ipconfig /flushdns & ipconfig /renew` with no luck.

Comment: are there any search DNS Suffixes listed in the Controlpanel Network applet for your lan interface IP v4 settings (click the advanced button and look at the DNS tab)? Windows appends these DNS suffixes in order when trying to resolve a non-FQDN name via DNS.

Comment: @FrankThomas, that was exactly it! If you put this as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` applet, select your LAN interface, and open its IPv4 settings. Click the Advanced button, and go to the DNS tab. remove any inappropriate entries you find in the box labeled "DNS Suffixes".

This tells the host to translate short names into fully qualified domain names by appending those DNS suffixes (in order of appearance) when querying a DNS server for them. Its functionality is identical to the linux `resolv.conf` "search" setting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about Linux, now I fully understand what that is for.